# Action Script function call from PHP error

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
var result:int;
if(observerButton.selected == true)
    result = assignMemberAsObserverToEvent(dataGrid.selectedItem.id_event,dataGrid2.selectedItem.id_person,assignmentDescription.text);
else if(adminButton == true) 
    result = assignMemberAsAdministratorToEvent(dataGrid.selectedItem.id_event,dataGrid2.selectedItem.id_person,assignmentDescription.text);
else
    alert("please select the assignment type");
```

There is error on two assign function calls.
The error is: Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type int.   AssignUser.mxml /pui2/src   line 149    Flex Problem

Here their declarations:

```
protected function assignMemberAsAdministratorToEvent(id_person:String, id_event:String, description:String):void
        {
            assignMemberAsAdministratorToEventResult.token = actions.assignMemberAsAdministratorToEvent(id_person, id_event, description);
        }


        protected function assignMemberAsObserverToEvent(id_person:String, id_event:String, description:String):void
        {
            assignMemberAsObserverToEventResult.token = actions.assignMemberAsObserverToEvent(id_person, id_event, description);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both `assignMemberAsAdministratorToEvent` and `assignMemberAsObserverToEvent`, you never return anything.  'void' is a type, and the compiler is trying to cast it into an int (your result var) in which it can't because they are not compatible.  Either remove the result var or make the functions return something.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions return void (i.e. nothing). You are then trying to store void or 'nothing' into an int.

The functions need to return something for `result` to hold a value